# Write column header to csv from dataframe if it doesn't exist pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I'm fetching data from an API and trying to store it in CSV. The API returns an array of objects like these:

First API call response

```json
[
 {name:'Alice',age:22, address:'123 Downtown'},
 {name:'Bob',age:25, address:'456 Downtown'}
]
```

Second API call response

```json
[
 {name:'Cherry',age:22, contact:'2222'},
 {name:'David',age:25, contact:'1111'}
]
```

To parse and store, this is what I'm currently doing:

```py
    while not allFetched:
        response = callApi()
        x = []
        for item in response['data']:
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([item])
            x.append(df)
        new = pd.concat(x, ignore_index=True)
        new.to_csv("Data.csv", mode='a', index=False, header=fileExists)
```

This adds the header once (if not fileExists) but messes up the column because the headers mismatch. I want to create the column header if it doesn't exist and have Nan in missing values as follows:

```
name,age,address,contact
Alice,22,123 Downtown,Nan
Bob,25,Nan,1111
```

Edit: Added responses from two API calls. The problem arrives when different API calls have different fields. How to add them to CSV without adding the entire header twice but only adding the additional columns without misaligning.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a json response. You can parse json with such structure using `pd.json_normalize()` method:

```
response = callApi()
dta = pd.json_normalize(response['data'])
```

Result:

```
|    | name   |   age | address      |   contact |
|---:|:-------|------:|:-------------|----------:|
|  0 | Alice  |    22 | 123 Downtown |       nan |
|  1 | Bob    |    25 | nan          |      1111 |
```

Then you can save the data frame to csv:

```
dta.to_csv("Data.csv", mode='a', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
import pandas as pd


data = [
    {'name':'Alice','age':22, 'address':'123 Downtown'},
    {'name':'Bob','age':25, 'contact':'1111'}
]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.fillna('Nan')

print(df)

df.to_csv("Data.csv", mode='a', index=False)
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
    name  age       address contact
0  Alice   22  123 Downtown     Nan
1    Bob   25           Nan    1111
```

**CSV Output:**

```
name,age,address,contact
Alice,22,123 Downtown,Nan
Bob,25,Nan,1111
```

Comment: Thanks, Sabil. But because I am making multiple API calls, the problem of header still exists. If two objects from "data" JSON are coming from two different API calls, how can I put them in the correct column without writing the header twice to CSV?

Comment: you can merge two json and then construct a csv

Comment: Okay. But what if I am fetching a large amount of data, say I'm making 10000 API call over some time. Is it wise to have it in memory and saving at the end?